# Scala: Iterating through an xml Node

Tags: xml, scala

There is no problem iterating through this:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
    <name>Kitten</name>
    <special>Yup</special>
    </entry>
    <entry>
    <name>Gato</name>
    <special>Nope</special>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

with this approach

```
for(entry <- data)
...
```

But now when I try to iterate within an entry

ie:

```
<entry>
<name>Kitten</name>
<special>Yup</special>
</entry>
```

I can't actually go through name and then proceed to special instead, it just treats this Node as one item and only goes through one cycle. How do I go through each and every element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `child` method, perhaps?

For example,

```
for (bar <- <foo><bar><kv/></bar><bar><kv/></bar></foo>.child; kv <- bar.child) {println (kv)}
```

prints

```
<kv/>
<kv/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of child elements from the root, regardless of depth, then you can do this:

```
val elems = xml.descendant.collect{case e:Elem => e}
```

The resulting `elems` will be a `List[Elem]` representing any child `Elem` from the root.